# mysql query to get sum and count

Tags: mysql, database

I am using the following query now...

```
SELECT id, account_number, 
       (SELECT count(*)
        FROM `member_tbl` t2
        WHERE t2.referred_by = t1.account_number
       ) AS total_referred
FROM `member_tbl` t1;
```

And that provides the following result...

```
id - id of memenr
account_number - account number of user
total_referred - total number of members referred by account_number
```

But we want to get some more results like following...

```
total_reffered2 - total number of members that THEY(all accounts referred by account_number) all referred

total_reffered3 - total number of members that referred by all members of total_reffered2
```

Please check [mysql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ecb21)

and as per [mysql fiddle data](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/970ec9), query must return following values...

```
| id | account_number  | referred_by1  | referred_by2 | referred_by3
+----+-----------------+---------------+--------------+-------------
|  1 | ac203003        | 0             | 0            | 0
+----+-----------------+---------------+--------------+-------------
|  2 | ac203004        | 1             | 1            | 0
+----+-----------------+---------------+--------------+-------------
|  3 | ac203005        | 2             | 1            | 1
+----+-----------------+---------------+--------------+-------------
```

Let me give you another example

If every member always had 10 referrals, then...

```
referred_by1 = 10
referred_by2 = 100
referred_by3 = 1000
```

I am confused, how do I write this query?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can just keep on the same path you are on, using more complex queries.  I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT id, account_number, 
       (SELECT count(*)
        FROM `member_tbl` t2
        WHERE t2.referred_by = t1.account_number
       ) AS total_referred,
       (SELECT count(*)
        FROM `member_tbl` t2 join
              member_tbl t3
              on t3.referred_by = t2.account_number
        WHERE t2.referred_by = t1.account_number
       ) AS refer4ed_by_2,
       (SELECT count(*)
        FROM `member_tbl` t2 join
              member_tbl t3
              on t3.referred_by = t2.account_number join
              member_tbl t4
              on t4.referred_by = t3.account_number
        WHERE t2.referred_by = t1.account_number
       ) AS referred_by_3
FROM `member_tbl` t1;
```

This doesn't match the "expected" results from SQL Fiddle.  But then again, the expected results don't even have the right number of rows, so they don't seem correct.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i will try that on main db, then i will let you know, thanks again.

Comment: Nice find but This will probably will be slow on the more larger set because EXPLAIN shows 6 rows off DEPENDENT SUBQUERY and indexing this won't speed it up

Comment: @RaymondN so what's the solution for speed? as our db is really big about 10,000 rows

Comment: Not figured that out just as Gordon Linoff is right you should move to the more complexe query but can you make a better output example based on your sql fiddle and your requirements please? because total_referred isn't being outputted in your example output

Comment: @seoppc . . . I would start by being sure there is an index on `member_tbl(account_number, referred_by)`.

Comment: it was late last night when i had made my comments... But indexing would properly speed it up. But a correlated subquery isnt the best way to solve a problem.